# How to forward example.com/anycharacters to same domain with https in Nginx?

Tags: linux, nginx

I want that whatever path the visitor/user types in the url bar after the main domain name, that request should be forwarded to a particular domain.
E.g. whether user types example.com or example.com/garbage/characters, he should be forwarded to https://example.com/somepath

Kindly tell how can I achieve this in Nginx. I've tried giving the server_name example.com/* but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you don't *forward* the request (that implies a reverse proxy,  the `proxy_pass` directive and the site visitor continuing to make insecure plain http requests to Nginx) but instruct the site visitor to make a new, secure, request over https with a *redirect*:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$servername$request_uri;
}
```

This preserves the complete URI  that your site visitor entered in their web browser and effectively instructs them to repeat the request only with `http://` replaced with `https://`.

To always redirect to a specific hostname, for example to always redirect to `example.com` and to strip the `www` from requests for `http://www.example.com/some/path` : replace the `$servername` parameter with the hostname `example.com`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Similarly you can replace `$request_uri` with a specific path to always redirect to one specific URI.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com/some-new/landing/page.html;
}
```

Comment: Shot in the bulls eye